# Check Google pay's authentication mode

Tags: google-pay, 3d-secure, strong-customer-authentication

I'd like to set my Google pay to accept both authentication modes: "PAN_ONLY" and "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS".
Then, during transaction flow, when I get the token, before I process the transaction - **how can I check which authentication mode was applied by google out of the 2 without decrypting the token?**

Why I want to do that:

1. if it's was tokenized in a 'PAN_ONLY' mode, I need to run 3DSecure myself, before processing the transaction
2. if it's 'CRYPTOGRAM_3DS' it means that the token is in DPAN mode and then I'd like to decrypt it (as a merchant)

Answer (score 0):

> how can I check which authentication mode was applied by google out of the 2 without decrypting the token?

You can request this information in the request with the [`CardParameters. assuranceDetailsRequired`](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#CardParameters) parameter. It will be returned as part of the [`CardInfo.assuranceDetails`](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/response-objects#assurance-details-specifications) response.

> if it's was tokenized in a 'PAN_ONLY' mode, I need to run 3DSecure myself, before processing the transaction

From https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/response-objects#assurance-details-specifications

> *Note: If both cardHolderAuthenticated and accountVerified are true, you don’t need to step up the returned credentials. **If both aren’t, we recommend you to run the same risk checks and , authentication including 3D Secure flow if applicable.***